# Ordering by Column in Matrix in Power BI

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax

I am very new to Power BI and I am trying to sort my columns in my matrix. Below shows an example of my matrix.

```
Code   March 2017     March 2018
AAT      2               
AAD                       3
AAC      1                11
AAF      3                2
AAH      10
```

I want to sort my data in descending order based on values in the March 2018 column. Thus the final matrix should be as follows.

```
Code   March 2017     March 2018
AAC      1                11
AAD                       3
AAF      3                2
AAT      2               
AAH      10
```

Note that the columns March 2017 and March 2018 come from a single column in my dataset called Period.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to sort by any column in a matrix by clicking on the column header.

[image: Matrix]

Clicking on the ellipsis in the top right corner should give you similar sorting option.

Comment: It doesn't let me sort by either of those methods. In the ellipsis it only says the options:Export data, Remove

Comment: Are you not using a matrix visual?

Comment: I am using a matrix visual

Comment: Nothing comes up when I hover over each column

Comment: Are you on an old version of PowerBI? This has been possible for quite some time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column

Comment: Oh I solved it. I needed to make my headers measures, not columns :)